# Quicksort Partition Algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to learn Quick Sort. To do so, I followed the logic for quick sort in [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/quick_sort_algorithm.htm) where the last element is picked as the pivot and you work through the array from both ends swapping elements as needed. Now after a long time of trying to come up with my own algorithm based on this, here is what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;

int a[] = {10,4,3,2,8,5};
int j;

int partition(int left, int right,  int array[]){
    int pivot = array[right];


    while(1){
        while(array[left]<pivot){
            left = left+1;

        }

        while(array[right]>pivot){
            right=right-1;

        }
        if(left>=right){

            return right;
        }

        int temp1 = array[left];
        int temp2 = array[right];
        array[left] = temp2;
        array[right] = temp1;
    }
}

void quicksort(int left, int right, int array[]){
    if(left<right){
        int p = partition(left, right, array);
        quicksort(left, p-1, array);

        quicksort(p+1, right, array);
    }
}

int main(){
    quicksort(0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])-1, a);

    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])); i++){
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }

}
```

So after testing this with various arrays of different sizes and elements, it does output a correctly sorted array however in the algorithms that I have found online (ex. Hoare's) they always decrement right and increment left at the start of the partition. Also the pivot does not move in most algorithms I have found, but I move it.

What I am wondering is, am I doing this wrong? Why does it work? It's been a lot of trial and error so that it be understandable if I did it wrong, I am also slightly new to algorithms and data structures so I wouldn't be surprised if I made some mistakes.

Comment: Sounds like your "question" would be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As you're asking to improve working code, this question is probably better placed at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If we accepted `Why does it work?` questions, there would be too many :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the pivot for Qsort, there's no fixed rule for selecting the pivot. Choosing the pivot really depends on which strategy you want to impose on your input data, and that largely depends on the properties of the input data - range, size etc.

Generally, we choose the pivot so that it splits the array into two equal halves (as much as possible). This is done so that we don't end up pushing all the elements on to one-side of the Qsort. If this happens your algorithm will become O(n^2) - think of skew trees if you're not able to see why.